# Trying to solve a related rates problem

Tags: calculus

I am trying to solve a related rates problem. The problem states:

If $y = 4x -x^3$ and the x-coordinate is increasing at the rate of 1/3 unit/sec. How fast is the slope of the graph changing at the instant when $x = 2$?

I have done this:

Let $\frac {dx}{dt} = \frac {1}{3}$ unit/sec

I derive the formula:
$\frac {dy}{dt} = 4 \frac {dx}{dt} - 3x^2 \frac {dx}{dt}$

I substitute to solve for $dy \over dt$.

$\frac {dy}{dt} = 4(\frac {1}{3}) - 3(2^2)(\frac {1}{3}) = \frac {-8}{3}$

and then I solve for the slope as (dy/dt)/(dx/dt) = (-8/3)/3 which is -8 unit/sec

But the answer is supposed to be -4 units/sec

What am I doing wrong?

Ted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** How fast the slope is changing is $\frac{dw}{dt}$ where $w=\frac{dy}{dx}$.  So you will be differentiating again.

**Added:** The question does not ask for the slope, it asks for the *rate of change* of the slope. We have $\frac{dy}{dx}=4-3x^2$, so the slope is $4-3x^2$.

For the rate of change of this, differentiate $4-3x^2$ with respect to $t$. We get that 
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=-6x\frac{dx}{dt}.$$
Since $\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{1}{3}$, when $x=2$ we have
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=(-6)(2)(1/3)=-4.$$

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean? What do I need to differentiate again

Comment: You need to differentiate $\frac{dy}{dx}$ with respect to $t$. This is because you are asked for the *rate of change* of the *slope*.

Comment: I was wondering, how would you simplify d/dt(dy/dx).. could you say that it also is d2y/d2x?

Comment: @TedFlethuseo: It isn't what you wrote down. But by the  the Chain Rule, it is what you wrote down, multiplied by $\frac{dx}{dt}$

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different explanation that some may follow more easily:

The trick here is reading the problem closely.  It asks for the **rate of change of the slope** (which is itself a rate of change).  The derivative of the function will give you the slope.  The second derivative will give you the rate of change of the slope (*the slope of the slope*).

Since the question is asking about the change in the slope of the equation $y = 4x-x^3$, the first order of business would be to get the equation for the slope (which is the derivative, $y^{'}$ or $\frac {dy}{dx}$):
$$y = 4x-x^3$$
$$ \frac {dy}{dx} = 4 - 3x^2$$

This is the equation for the slope of the function.  So we don't let confusing notation get in the way, let's just call this equation for slope $s$.  So, $s = 4 - 3x^2$.

Now we want to know how the slope is changing with time.  We know that $x$ is increasing at a rate of $1 \over 3$ units/sec and we want to know how the slope changes with small changes in $x$.  In other words, we were given $\frac {dx}{dt}$ and we want to find $\frac {ds}{dt}$.  So, we take the derivative of $s$ with respect to time:

$$\frac {ds}{dt} = -6x \frac {dx}{dt}$$

Substituting known values, 
$$\frac {ds}{dt} = -6 \cdot 2 \cdot \frac {1}{3} = -4$$